# Отрисовка квадрата на изображении с зазорами

Tags: python, python-3.6, pillow

Требуется нарисовать 10 квадратиков в линию с небольшими зазорами, как бы я не пытался, я не понимаю где у этих 4 атрибутов `x` - длинна и `y` - высота как это правильно реализовать? При смене одного из параметров куб да перемещается, но так же меняется и его размер(

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

#Создаем пустое изображение
img = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), (0,0,0))

#Получаем объект рисования для нашей пикчи
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

x = 10
y = 10

#Рисуем 10 квадратов с небольшими зазорами.
for _ in range(10):
    draw.rectangle((25,25,x,y), fill='blue', outline=(255, 0, 0))
    x += 15

img.show()
```

Что я имею на выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно (квадраты должны быть одного и того же размера как самый первый, рисовалось в ручную поэтому разные размеры):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот так нормально рисует:

```
    draw.rectangle((x,y,x+25,y+25), fill='blue', outline=(255, 0, 0))
    x += 35
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут же начальные координаты и конечные, а у вас начальные координаты были одни и те же, каждый раз рисовался всё более широкий прямоугольник, от одних и тех же координат. А надо разные рисовать и сдвигать `x` на величину, *большую* чем ширина квадрата, тогда получится зазор.

Из [документации](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html):

> PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle(xy, fill=None, outline=None)
>
> xy – Four points to define the bounding box. Sequence of either [(x0,
> y0), (x1, y1)] or [x0, y0, x1, y1]. The second point is just outside
> the drawn rectangle.

Т.е. задаются начальные координаты прямоугольника и потом конечные координаты (причём, они уже снаружи прямоугольника).

Comment: спасибо теперь все стало на свои места)